# smoke simulation zooms in and crashes

Tags: camera, smoke-simulation

smoke simulation zooms in and crashes. Viewport is rendering this fine, but when I render the animation the first frame renders properly sometimes, and other times it renders like on the right.
Then blender will crash on the second or third frame.

And yet other times it will render and then save a blank image.

i am using the Version 2.83.1
gpu RTX2070S

render settings
samples 256
adaptive sampling

light paths =12
defuse=2
glossy=3
volume=2

volumes
step render rate 1
max steps 2048

performance
tile size 128x128

i attempted to lessen the quality of the bake settings and rendering it and had the same issues.

[image]

Comment: CPU? GPU? Settings for the simulation? Blender version? Please edit your question and add more information.